# Visual Studio 2005 + AjaxToolkit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET Web application. I am building it with Visual Studio 2005. One of my user controls requires the AJAX Control Toolkit. For some reason though, my project will not build. However, I have referenced the AjaxControlToolkit assembly. It is appearing in the project references.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this application will not build?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you mention the specific build error?

Comment: I receive errors like

"The type or namespace name "UpdatePanel" does not exist in the namespace "System.Web.UI"

"Element "ModalPopupExtender" is not a known element

Answer (score 3):

The UpdatePanel is part of `System.Web.Extensions.dll` and does not need to be explicitly added to the bin folder of the project as it gets installed into the GAC (global assembly cache).

See the [ASP.NET AJAX documentation](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/InstallingASPNETAJAX.aspx) for more information. The [ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0 msi can be downloaded here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/archive/).

*(I'll leave the rest of the answer here as it may prove useful for someone else)*

---

It sounds like the AJAX Control Toolkit is not referenced in the page. Make sure you have

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
```

in the code-behind.

Also, you might want to add this to the `web.config`

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

This specifies the tag prefix for the AJAX Control Toolkit controls when used in the aspx markup.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/ ...

> Note: This Septemeber 2009 release: Toolkit version 3.0.30930 is only
>   for users who are **building on top of .NET Framework 3.5** using
>   Visual Studio 2008.
>
> If you are using .NET Framework 2.0 and **Visual Studio 2005** then
>   you should use the earlier Toolkit version 1.0.20229 at CodePlex.

So unfortunately, if you're still developing in VS2005, you are stuck with a very old and buggy version of the Ajax

For .Net 2.0 (**not** 3.5!), download it from [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121).

**Please note:** If your web app is using a mix of .Net 2 and 3.5 or more, you can **theoritically** have two (or more) versions of the Ajax installed to cater for more than one .Net framework. But you have to give them separate assemblies. See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1509770.aspx?Adding%202%20versions%20of%20AjaxControlToolKit%20in%20one%20ASP%20NET%20application) and [here](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html).