# two different version of AjaxControlToolkit in same web application

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two different version of AjaxControlToolkit dll and I have added reference of both dll in my web application.  I also set up control tagprefix in web.config.

Now one of the page is using 1.0 version and I want to use 3.0 version in another page.  I am getting following error.

"The server tag 'ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender' is ambiguous. Please modify the associated registration that is causing ambiguity and pick a new tag prefix."

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: welcome to DLL hell, even though this one is a self inflicted wound.

Comment: How to solve DLL hell?  :) I wanted to understand what is side by side assembly execution?  Isn't it to run multiple version of the same DLL side by side? 

Why compiler doesn't know what dll I try to use If I have given different tagprefix for both DLL?

Answer (score 1):

you can not use two different version Ajax toolkit in single solution website application.

just use single Ajax toolkit version.

Comment: then what is side by side assembly execution?  Isn't it to run multiple version of the same DLL side by side?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the most updated version of the tool kit, why would you need to use the older one on a separate page?

Comment: Because the I do have third party page that I have integrated on my web application that uses latest version and my other pages still uses 1.0 version.   I am little bit worried that if I change reference to use 3.5 version to my pages, it might break even though it supports back ward compatibility. I wanted to understand what is side by side assembly execution? Isn't it to run multiple version of the same DLL side by side? Why compiler doesn't know what dll I try to use If I have given different tagprefix for both DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a [`<%@ Register...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28VS.71%29.aspx) with the toolkit version 3.0 as `Assembly` attribute to your page help?

EDIT: Personally, I have not done something like this.
Is it possible for you to change the `tagPrefix` to some other name to see if it works?
Where are the DLLs for toolkit installed? GAC?

Comment: I added that in web.config. And also I tried adding on page but still same issue

Comment: I have specify different tagePrefix for both of the DLL and I have to otherwise it will throw another compiler error because compiler gets confused where to look for.  

And Yes I have installed in GAC and also tried having in Bin folder.  but no luck...

Comment: Ok..  There is no way to run two different version of same assembly under same application. Either I have to compile the assembly source code into different name or have to upgrade my web application to use only one version.

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-ajaxcontroltoolkit

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the source version specific for the .Net frameworks you have in your web application and recompile one or the other, with a different assembly name.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624879/visual-studio-2005-ajaxtoolkit/34302192#34302192) and [here](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html).